# Adding file from project in TFS to a different project

Tags: vb.net, tfs

I have a couple of modules in a project in TFS that I would like to use as the starting point for a new project. I don't want the exact modules but much of them are useful in the new project. The second project is pretty much entirely different from the first with the exception these modules. Again the modules will be modified from the original.

Is there good way to add these to the new project? I code in VB 2008.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The big picture is that TFS does care much where you store your code;  regardless of how many Team Projects you create,  yours our e code is stored under the same root ($/) and as long as you have permission to access the source you can navigate to it. Under most circumstances you will want only 1 copy of your source sitting in source control somewhere.

That being said, you have a bunch if options... Of them all, the simplest choice is to keep the source where it is and adjust access permissions to it in order allow other team members (in other team projects) to get to it.  Then create workspace mappings to control where it puts that source on your local machine when you perform a get latest.

If you plan for that code to change independently for each solution you can either make a copy of it and check it in (treating it as new code), or you can branch it from its current location to the new location by right-clicking on each folder you want to branch and selecting the option to branch after creating the new Team Project.  The target location eould be a folder in your under the new Team Project.  Typically, these latter 2 options are not recommended because then you would then be maintaining multiple copies of your code, which can get expensive!